# Urban Airship integration with Cordova iOS throwing

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, urbanairship.com

I've got an AngularJS web app wrapped into Cordova (iOS platform). Having added the Urban Airship plugin ([urbanairship-cordova](https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push)), I receive the following error when running:

```
$ npm-exec cordova run ios --device
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: Cannot find module '../ConfigParser/ConfigParser'
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

The version requirements for the UA plugin are Cordova 5.0.0+ and Cordova iOS 3.8.0+. I'm running Cordova 5.4.0 (latest at time of writing), any previous 5.x.x versions produce a separate issue in the Angular app with some image assets not appearing.

But the above `ConfigParser` error only appears in 5.4.0.

If I revert the UA plugin installation, the error goes away. And I get the same error when trying to emulate with iOS simulator.

I've contacted Urban Airship (Twitter) as the Github repo has issues turned off, though their support page (http://goo.gl/ZGrbbi) says I should log issues there.

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an incompatibility with the latest version of Cordova and the UA plugin.

For now you can roll back your global version of Cordova to version 5.3.3 with npm;

`npm install -g cordova@5.3.3`

It'd be worth contacting Urban Airship to explain your problem via email at support@urbanairship.com as advised on the GitHub repo https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the config parser script moved in 5.4.0. Will be fixed in the next release.

Update: We just released 4.0.0 version of the UA plugin. Should be compatible with the latest cordova versions.